# Pointer to slice of interfaces in function parameter

Tags: function, pointers, go, parameters

I have the following function:

```
func read(filePath string, structure *[]interface) {
    raw, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    json.Unmarshal(raw, structure)
}
```

Which I call like this:

```
    indexes := []Index
    read(path + "/" + element + ".json", &indexes)
```

However, I'm getting strange error that vanish when I take off `structure *[]interface` from the function declaration:

```
./index.verb.go:73: syntax error: unexpected ), expecting {
```

I think something wront when I try to pass a pointer to a slice of generic type. How should I do it then? I can't do `structure *[]Index` because there are other types I wanna return too

Comment: if you run `go fmt` it will tell you the precise location of your syntax error, and in this case even what character is expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the function like this:

```
func read(filePath string, structure interface{}) error {
  raw, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filePath)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }
  return json.Unmarshal(raw, structure)
}
```

The `structure` value is passed through to `json.Unmarshal` and can be any type supported by `json.Unmarshal`.

Call it like this:

```
var indexes []Index
err := read(path + "/" + element + ".json", &indexes)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
    os.Exit(1)
}
```